# Does such a mathematician exist in the present days?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

In the last sentence of Page 4 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9404236.pdf), Thurston mentioned (rephrased and tailored for the current purpose) it is common that excellent mathematicians don't even know the standard formal usage of quantifiers. I guess he must refer to those "ancient" mathematicians before Hilbert. Am I right? If not, I need an example of such a mathematician in the present days.

Comment: So why is -1???

Comment: Mathematicians? No. It might be useful to note that Thurston was a brilliant and prolific mathematician who often came up with the brilliant geometric ideas underlying his results and lthen eft the details to his grad students or others to work out, after the hard work was done.

Comment: @GaryMoore The original sentence "it is common for excellent mathematicians not even to know the standard **formal** usage of quantifiers (for all and there exists), yet all mathematicians **certainly perform the reasoning that they encode**" is not exaclty the sentence you have written ("it is common that excellent mathematicians don't even know the standard usage of quantifiers"). The difference is clear from the bold text (which I've added), I believe.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would hazard to guess that it is because your question isn't really appropriate for this site.

Comment: More likely, that assertion was an over-statement or figurative... based on an arguably true fact that (in my observation) very good mathematicians have a nearly automatic intuition for the sort of thing that gets quantified as "order of quantifiers", or as formal quantifiers, as opposed to "natural language" descriptions of the same things. E.g., they'd not fall into the same traps that people fumbling with newly-heard definitions might.

Comment: @Pedro, Yes. And your point is?? I did not quote it literally, but note that I gave the link.

Comment: @GaryMoore It seems for me that you are asking for something whose existence was not stated by Thurston.

Comment: I think what is meant here is that in formal mathematical logic, you would rather write $\forall x (x \in \Bbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2 \geq 0)$ instead of $x^2 \geq 0 \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$. Nevertheless, since it is 100% clear what is meant and the second notation is more convenient, the second notation is often preferred in other parts of mathematics.

Comment: @Pedro, okay I see your point. For me, I understand it as paul garrett above.

Comment: @PhoemueX, That is a nice point! I did not note that. In my mental picture, I somehow thought of it as there are mathematicians who cannot even write "for every ... there is" correctly, which would be absurd for a modern mathematician as far as I can tell.

Comment: What he meant is that it is hard and useless to use correctly the quantifiers in every statement. When those are implied by the context, it is better to avoid them for readability.

Comment: @reuns, I guess one of my problems is what Thurston means by "correct usage". Is the criterion logician's or mathematician's?

Comment: Yes. We always use a compromise between readability and rigor. What is correct is what works.

Comment: @reuns, If you agree with that, then your previous comment does not hold.